# On the weak semantics of references-to-const (and pointers-to-const)

Tags: c++, constants, const-reference

This has probably been already asked.

Why is it allowed to assign a reference-to-const to a non-const variable?

Why is this allowed

```cpp
int mut {0};
const int & r_to_c {mut};
mut = 1;
// now r_to_c changed to 1!
// But it was supposed to be a reference to something constant!
```

?

Sure, I cannot mutate the value from the reference-to-const itself. I cannot

```cpp
r_to_c = 2;
```

but isn't the `const` qualification enforcing too little? I would expect, from a promise of const-ness, that binding to mutable variables was disallowed.

Otherwise what guarantees is `const` giving me? They seem pretty weak, and it seems that this could easily trick programmers to shoot themselves in their foot.

I know that C++ has a reputation for allowing people to shoot themselves in their foot. I don't have a problem with *allowing* dangerous things. In this case, my problem is that in this case it seems that it is purposefully deceiving, given that the semantics of `const` here is not the one would expect it.

Mine is a question about the compiler and the language semantics, not about references in particular (I could have asked the same question using a pointer-to-const that is assigned to the address of a non-const variable. Like `int mut{0}; const int * p_to_c{&mut};`).

**Why is the semantics of a reference-to-const (or pointer-to-const) just "you can't use this particular window to modify the thing you see (but if you have other windows that are non-const, you can modify it)" instead of a more powerful "this can only be a window to something that was declared constant and that the compiler guarantees it stays constant"?**

---

[Note on terminology: I use the expression "reference-to-const" instead of "const reference" because a "const reference", interpreted as `T& const` - consistently with calling `T* const` a "const pointer" -, does not exist.]

Comment: "I cannot mutate the value from the reference-to-const": `const_cast<int&>(r_to_c) = 1`

Comment: Analogy: I let you have keys to my house, with the understanding that you're not allowed to rearrange the furniture. Shouldn't I be allowed to rearrange the furniture while you have those keys?

Comment: Constant reference is just a read-only view on the object, nothing more.

Comment: Thank you @Quimby. That's probably the most concise answer to my doubts, and at the same it suggested the better naming my mind was looking for: "readonly reference" would be a much better name than "reference to const" (it would create less confusion around the semantics). In C# they got this (the naming) right, with the `readonly` modifier.

Comment: `readonly` is slightly different, it is run-time version of `const` values. Because `const` used during object definition (e.g. `const int x=10;`) creates a truly constant object that must be initialized with compile-time constant expression and the value cannot be changed during run-time. C++ does not really have a `readonly` feature.

Comment: My comment was a bit confusing. I just meant `readonly` would be a good name to use in C++ instead of `const` when used to qualify references/pointers. For example `readonly int &` instead of `const int &`. I would read that as "readonly reference to int", and its semantics would be clear: with that reference I can only read something, not write to it (this doesn't imply that the referenced thing cannot be changed from elsewhere). Thank you for pointing out the actual semantics of `readonly` in C#, which is basically a run-time constant, which C++ doesn't have (is it a big limitation?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> but isn't the const qualification enforcing too little? I would expect, from a promise of const-ness, that binding to mutable variables was disallowed.

No it is not "too little". You are expecting the wrong thing.

First, whether you bind a const reference does not make the object itself `const`. That would be strange:

```
void foo(int& x) {
    static const int& y = x;
}
```

When I call `foo`:

```
int x = 42;
foo(x);
```

I cannot know whether somebody else will keep a `const` reference to my non-const `x`.

> Otherwise what guarantees is const giving me?

You cannot modify something via a `const` reference:

```
void bar(const int& x);
int x = 0;
bar(x);
```

When I call a function that takes a `const&` then I know that it will not modify my (non-const) parameter. If const references would not bind to non-const objects then there would be no way to make this last example work, i.e. you could pass non-const objects only to functions that do modify them, but not to functions that do not modify them.

P.S. I can understand your confusion. It is sometimes overlooked that holding a constant reference does not imply that the object cannot be modified. Consider this example:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
    const int& x;
};

int main() {
    int y = 0;
    foo f{x};
    std::cout << f.x;   // prints 0
    y = 42;
    std::cout << f.x;   // prints 42
}
```

Printing the value of the member to the screen yields two different results, even though `foo::x` is a constant reference! It is a "constant reference" not a "reference to a constant". What `const` actually means here: You cannot modify `y` through `f.x`.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize you were still modifying the answer, I would have waited to make the minor edits.

Comment: @cigien yes, interleaved edits.  Some of yours I already included, you can go ahead to fix the ones I missed ;)

Comment: "If const references would not bind to non-const obejcts then there would be no way to [...] pass non-const objects only to functions that do modify them" Good point, thank you. This is a valid point for which the semantics that I would wish for is not possible. Then I guess in the end my frustration is just about the naming. "Reference-to-const" makes one think that you have... a reference to a constant, while in fact it'd better be called something like "Reference-by-which-you-cannot-mutate", since the `const` qualification is just a statement on the reference, and not on the pointed object.

Answer (score 3):

The ability to bind a const-reference to a mutable variable is actually a very valuable feature to have in the language. Consider that we might want to have a mutable variable.

```
int mut {0};
// ... some time later
mut = 1;
```

This is perfectly reasonable; it's a variable that is going to change during the execution of the program.

Now let's say we want to print the value of this variable, and would like to write a function to do that.

```
void print(int param)  // or 'int &' to avoid a copy, 
                       // but the point here is that it's non-const 
{
  std::cout << param;
}
```

This is fine, but clearly the function is not changing the parameter. We would like that to be enforced so that mistakes like `param = 42;` are caught by the compiler. To do that, we would make `param` a `const &` parameter.

```
void print(int const & param);
```

It would be quite unfortunate if we couldn't call this function with arguments that are non-const. After all, we don't care that the parameter *might* be modified outside the function. We just want to say that the parameter is guaranteed not to be modified by `print`, and binding a `const &` to a mutable variable serves exactly that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. As I answered to @largest_prime_is_463035818, this is a valid reason why we can't have the semantics that I would like. Having understood that, then I'm only left with some frustration for the naming, as "Reference-to-const" could be confusing when read in plain English, while a more precise naming would be "Reference-by-which-you-cannot-mutate" (but certainly it isn't short).

Comment: @MichelePiccolini I personally find the meaning of `const` to be clear in this case, but that just depends upon one's comfort with the language. More generally, welcome to programming: natural language is imprecise, with good reason, and programming languages are precise, with good reason. There will always be some issues like the one you're facing when describing one in terms of the other; it's just a reality we have to live with :)

Comment: now the meaning is perfectly clear to me too, thanks to yours and others' answers. @Quimby put it very concisely as "Constant reference is just a read-only view on the object". I can now reduce my complaints to "I wish the modifier was called `readonly` instead of `const`, as it would be more clear". But we can't have a perfect world :)

Comment: @MichelePiccolini Another exampel where `const` is not as strong as you might expect: If you have a `const Foo f;` and do `auto x = f.x; f.bar(); bool is_it_really_constant = x == f.x;` then `is_it_really_constant` might be `false` when `f::x` is `mutable`.

Answer (score 1):

A reference to a const object is not the same as a const reference to a non const object, but C++'s type system does not distinguish them.

This is sort of a violation of the LSP; it has the same kind of problem as a reference to a mutable square and rectangle do.

You can create "true const" but you need help at declaration.

```
template<class T>
struct true_const {
  const T value;
};
```

a `true_const<int>&` or `true_const<T> const&` can be passed around as a reference, and nobody can edit it (without invoking UB) "behind your back".

Of course, a function taking a true const cannot also take a normal object.

```
void bob( true_const<int>& x ) {
  auto local = x.value;
  call_some_other_function();
  assert(local == x.value); // guaranteed to be true
}

void bob( const int& x ) {
  auto local = x;
  call_some_other_function();
  assert(local == x); // NOT guaranteed to be true
}
```

`const` fields in classes are truly const; modifying them is undefined behavior.

A thin wrapper around a type that is const within the class is thus a guarantee the data is `const`.  Then take a reference to that.

Now, the `true_const` could use some operator support.

```
template<class T>
struct true_const {
  const T value;
  constexpr T const& get() const { return value; }
  constexpr T const& operator*() const { return get(); }
  constexpr T const* operator->() const { return std::addressof(value); }
  constexpr operator T const&() const { return get(); }

  // concepts-defended operator+,==, etc
};
```

Comment: Interesting. Could you elaborate a bit more? With the first sentence you mean that `ref` in `const int var {0}; int& ref {var};` cannot be distinguished from `ref` in `int var {0}; const int& ref {var};`? And what is the problem of the mutable square and rectangle that you are referring to? Finally, can you make an example on how the idiom that you showed would implement a "true const"?

Comment: @MichelePiccolini A mutable rectangle has `auto beforeH = r.getHeight(); r.setWidth(x); assert(r.getHeight() == beforeH);` as true; a square does not.  Naively, a square is a type of rectangle, but it isn't true.  The same is true here; a reference to an immutable object appears to be a subtype of a reference to a mutable object, but is not.